# Fabricjs cloning canvas removes decimals from rectangle

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I've got the following code which clones a canvas in fabricjs:

```
 var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');    
 canvas.width = 644.51234567;
 canvas.height = 644.51234567;
 var rect = new fabric.Rect({
       left: 0,
       top: 0,
       width: canvas.width,
       height: canvas.height,
       fill: 'rgba(255,127,39,1)',
       strokeWidth: 0
    });
canvas.add(rect);        
canvas.renderAll();

canvas.clone(function(cloneCanvas) {    
  canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
    alert("Width of original rect: "+obj.width);
  }); 
  cloneCanvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
    alert("Width of cloned rect: "+obj.width);
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s35fxaby/8/

As you can see by running the code, cloning the canvas changes the number of decimals on the rectangle.
This is an issue for me as the rest of my code is dependent on the decimals being the same for the original and the duplicate.

Is there anything I can do about this - like preventing the clone function from rounding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#.NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS)

`fabric.Object.NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS = 10;`

value = number of digit you want after decimal.

The default value is 2.

Comment: Is there any other alternative property available for canvas background image ?
because this property is not working for background image.

Comment: @mayurkukadiya, can you create a fiddle?